# Correct way to backup via Time Machine to a remote Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

If I have a MacBook through which I will like to access a Remote Time Capsule via Back to My Mac in order to perform updates to my Time Machine backup on said Time Capsule, which should be the correct settings o accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to run a VPN server on the network where the Time Capsule sits so that your remote machine can log in over the internet as if it were a local computer.

This pokes holes in the network since most people don't allow their Time Capsule to be reachable by anyone on the internet and have their entire home network hidden behind a router with a local and non-routable internet address.

OS X server would be an inexpensive and well documented / supported manner of setting up a VPN or sharing any hard drive with others for Time Machine backups as well as enabling a local Time Capsule to be reachable directly by VPN clients.

Comment: Thanks; after trying different alternatives, I think this may be my best option, since I actually have a mac mini turned on in my Network all day. Regards,